# Is it possible to remove a filter from a CSS file on an overriden CSS file?

Tags: css

I have a CSS File that contains a rule like this:

```
.someElement {
    filter:gray(enabled=true) alpha(opacity=50);
    -ms-filter:"gray(enabled=true) alpha(opacity=50)"
}
```

This rule causes some issues and I would like to remove it. However, making changes to that CSS File is annoying to say the least, and the ideal situation would be to create a secondary CSS file that overrides/removes that rule.

I assume this isn't possible? (without JavaScript or so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your new CSS file and make sure it gets loaded AFTER the original one.

```
.someElement {
    filter:gray(enabled=false);
    -ms-filter:"gray(enabled=false)";
}
```

Tested in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/H7msL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context.
you can create inline css and override it.
or you can create a second css file to override and call it after the first.

Opps didn't see your answer